# java class declaration with the generic type disable method returning another generic type

Tags: java, class, generics, declaration, subtype

I have this little problem and I want to find out whay is this happening to me:
I made class like this:

```
public class SomeSimpleClass {
   //and I had method who returns generic. it can be instance of whatever, and for sure can be casted to U:
   public <U>U giveMeSomething(String arg) {
      return (U)SomewhereSomething.getValueCastingIsOK(arg);
   }
}
```

and then I am using it like this:

```
// give me some number:
Integer number = instanceSomeSimpleClass.giveMeSomething("I want integer value");
```

OR

```
String text = instanceSomeSimpleClass.giveMeSomething("I want text now");
```

and everything is ok. getValueCastingIsOK from SomewhereSomething returns me what I want, and I dont need type cast on the giveMeSomething. Looks like the U is replaced by the type from the associative variable.. and everything is cool..

BUT then I create a new class:

```
public class SomeOtherClass <T extends Something> {
   //And I have the exactly same method here:
   public <U>U giveMeSomething(String arg) {
      return (U)SomewhereSomething.getValueCastingIsOK(arg);
   }   
}
```

and now when I want to use it in the same way, the compiler (I am using Java 1.7) is telling me, that I have to use typecast, and start to using the giveMeSomething like this, because U is now the Object, and nothing else...

```
Integer number = (Integer)instanceSomeSimpleClass.giveMeSomething("I want integer value");
```

:(

Why in the second case the compiler cant get the U type in the same way, as in the first case. And what I have to do, to be that this way?

Thank for an answers, suggestions.. ;)

Comment: sorry I forget.. the declaration is: public <U>U giveMeSomething(String arg)

Comment: Are you using the raw type of `SomeOtherClass`?

Comment: yes: SomeOtherClass instanceSomeSimpleClass = new SomeOtherClass();

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using a raw type of the class `SomeOtherClass`, but not supplying any type parameters to your declaration:

```
SomeOtherClass instanceSomeSimpleClass = new SomeOtherClass();
```

When you do this, the Java compiler will replace ALL generics in the class with the type erasure version, even unrelated generics such as your generic method.  The type erasure of the method

```
public <U>U giveMeSomething(String arg) {
```

becomes

```
public Object giveMeSomething(String arg) {
```

which requires the cast to `Integer`.

You must either supply a type parameter to `SomeOtherClass` (useless, unless you've eliminated unnecessary code that uses `T` to post the class code here):

```
SomeOtherClass<Something> instanceSomeSimpleClass = new SomeOtherClass<Something>();
```

Or you can remove the type parameter on the class definition, as you had it originally:

```
public class SomeSimpleClass {
```

Either will keep the generic method intact and eliminate the need to cast the return type of `giveMeSomething`.

Comment: Actualy this isnt absolutely true. Just partially. I made a test where I specified the generic U only, and this works. I tryed something like this:  public <U extends String>U giveMeSomething(String arg) and it was ok for the String return type, not for the Integer for sure.. So, it looks like Any specialization of the Any generic type turns on the generic mapping and disable the default Objects, as you are right, in this case. Now just to find out, how I can make a trick to switch it in the compiler time without destroing the main skeleton code :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the java syntax for explicit typing:

```
public <U>U giveMeSomething(String arg) {
    return SomewhereSomething.<U>getValueCastingIsOK(arg);
}
```

Notice the `<U>` between the dot and the method name. Notice also that casting is now not required.

That's how you explicitly declare what the type is for a typed method. Without this, java must *infer* the type, which it can't here, so (unsafe) casting is required.

Another example to illustrate. In this case, java can infer the type is `Integer` because of the type that the result is being assigned to:

```
Integer number = instanceSomeSimpleClass.giveMeSomething("I want integer value");
```

But if you were to use the value without assigning it, you'd need to pass to type:

```
someIntegerRequired(instanceSomeSimpleClass.<Integer>giveMeSomething("I want integer value"));
```

Comment: Thanks, the SomewhereSomething.<U>getValueCastingIsOK(arg); popups the problem into the another responsibilty. But because it is closed library object, there is nothing I can do with it. The type of the U is given by the type of the associator, and if we dont give this information to the compiler, it will work in the same way as it is the super type Object. (Without association will be swallowed by JVM) But without the exlicit typing of the SomeOtherClass, when you create the  instanceSomeSimpleClass instance, you cant use giveMeSomething() without the casting. This was actually the problem